# What is EOF!! in the bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

There is a command I don't understand:

```
custom_command << EOF!!
```

I want to ask what EOF!! is in the bash script. I did find EOF with google, but google will ignore the "!!" automatically, so I cannot find EOF!!.

I know the end of the file token, but I don't exactly know what it means with the "!!" in the script. Is this a mark to force something to do something like in vim's wq! ?

Plus, why and when should we use EOF!! instead of EOF?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1479; not that it'll help you here...

Comment: [Heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)!

Comment: I know "EOF", but I don't understand "EOF!!"

Comment: hmm.. doesn't make sense. where have you seen this? please post complete example. also: there's no such thing as "end of file token".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the command line, `!!` would be expanded to the last command executed. Bash will print the line for you:

```
$ ls
a.txt  b.txt
$ cat <<EOF!!
cat <<EOFls
>
```

In a script, though, history expansion is disabled by default, so the exclamation marks are part of the word.

```
#! /bin/bash
ls
cat <<EOF!!
echo 1
EOFls
echo 2
```

Produces:

```
a.txt  b.txt
script.sh: line 7: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF!!')
echo 1
EOFls
echo 2
```

To enable history and history expansion in a script, add the following lines:

```
set -o history
set -H
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use whatever string as here document terminator.

`EOF!!` is just what the person writing the script decided to use.

Comment: No, in bash `EOF!!` will be replaced by `EOF<whatever your previous command was>`

Comment: @knittl It won't, `!!` is only replaced in interactive scripts.

Comment: Right.  History expansion isn't enabled in non-interactive mode by default.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a weird [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Example:

```
cat << EOF!!
blabla
EOF!!
```

Note: this only works in script files. The command line parser interprets `!!`.

Answer (score 0):

As others already wrote, this is a here-document.

The token used for that should be chosen carefully; as the probability that the here-document contains `EOF!!` is lower than for `EOF` itself, they chose that.

I suppose they checked it does not harm before using it; `!!` in a script does NOT refer to the history, but it stays as it is.

Answer (score -1):

[The bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) lists this under ["Event designators"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators), saying:

> `!!`
>
> Refer to the previous command. This is a synonym for !-1`.

I simply searched for "bash manual double exclamation".